# French equivalent of the English “internet meme”?

Tags: expressions, anglais, néologismes

In English, an *internet meme* is an activity, concept, catchphrase or piece of media which spreads, often as mimicry, from person to person via the Internet. Some notable examples being: the *Harlem Shake*, or the *doge*.

I was wondering what the French equivalent might be, if any ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The word you’re looking for is simply “[mème](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A8me)”.

Comment: The translation *is* accurate, but it's not yet used as much as the english counterpart. Many french speakers know *meme* from the Internet without knowing that the french word exists and predates the web.

Comment: ...simplement le mème. :)

Answer (score 7):

The word, [*meme*](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=meme), used in the expression "*Internet meme*", is a short form of the Greek word *mimēma*; the French word is identical except for the accented *è*:

> **[mème](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/13563/3177) Internet**
>
> *Définition*
>  Élément culturel propagé de façon virale sur le Web.
>
> *Notes*
>  Le mème Internet peut notamment prendre la forme d'une
>   vidéo, d'un site Internet, d'un mot, d'une phrase, d'un personnage ou
>   d'un phénomène.
>
> mème Internet n. m. [...]
>
> [ *Le grand dictionnaire terminologique* (GDT) - [*mème Internet*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26522991) ]

See also: [*Termium*](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=&index=ent&__index=ent&srchtxt=meme&comencsrch.x=0&comencsrch.y=0), [*Wikipédia*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A8me_Internet). Note the word's absence from [*FranceTerme*](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/result?francetermeSearchTerme=m%C3%A8me), so there may indeed not be a set usage. On the other hand, as someone pointed out, it is not necessarily the first time such words have been used(see for instance [this](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=17076397) and [this](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=17062148)). The *mème Internet* is seen as a specific instance of the word *mème*; it is functionally distinct from [Dawkins'](http://www.webcitation.org/6HzDGE9Go) original idea.<sup>1</sup> Surely many people would understand you if you asked: "Tu connais le (*mème Internet* du) *Harlem Shake/doge* ?".

---

<sub>1. When the term is not used, the "it went viral" idiom will often be leveraged with verbs describing a change of state, such as with "*ce clip est devenu viral - un clip viral*" (has become; could be used with *blague*, *chanson*, *image* etc., but not as a technique [it seems](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/result?francetermeSearchTerme=viral%20marketing)). Similarly, you may find expressions such as "*ça c'est/un clip qui s'est... répandu/propagé comme une [traînée](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/tra%C3%AEn%C3%A9e) de poudre*" (which spread like *wildfire*); depending on context it could simply be summed up in a familiar way as "*un truc accrocheur, populaire, à la page, un phénomène, qu'on voit partout dans Internet ou sur le Web/la Toile et donc que « tous » connaissent*.".</sub>

Answer (score 0):

It is also often said using the english prononciation for the first **e**: ***mime***

This is used to underline the comic action, just like a **mime artist** do.