# How do you translate "dank memes" into French? Or rather, what is the French equivalent of a dank meme in English?

Tags: vocabulaire

I'm trying to translate this for a friend from France.

Answer (score 4):

I may not share this opinion with everyone, but I generally don't translate when it comes from the internet, especially memes. With my friends we say "*dank memes*" in French, and we all understand. We get them from English sources anyway so we don't mind.

But if you're trying to explain it to him I guess you'll have to use French. I'd also say something like "*des memes qui défoncent*", or "*des memes de qualité*" if you're mimicking a posh connoisseur.

Comment: "Qui tuent" de @jllagre est vraiment pas mal :-) Mais bon, c'est juste un choix personnel. Assez d'accord pour ne pas tout traduire, ca devient difficile ou maladroit.

Comment: "des memes de qualité" est absolument utilisée en Français. C'est à mes yeux la meilleur traduction possible, même si elle n'est pas littérale .

Answer (score 3):

"Dank" might be translated by *qui déchire* ou *qui défonce bien* (like "dank weed".)

The French translation for "[meme](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/13561/french-equivalent-of-the-english-internet-meme)" is the neologism *[mème](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A8me_Internet)* (also [oqlf](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26522991)), with a grave accent not to confuse with *même* = same, which has a circumflex.

However, this word is largely unknown in France so I would advise to add an explanation about it. To translate "Dank memes", I would then venture:

> [...] des mèmes<sup>1</sup> qui tuent [...]
>   ...

<sup>1</sup> Sur Internet, reprises virales et détournements humoristiques d'une expression, une photo, etc.

Comment: Très bien :-), mieux que "qui déchire", "qui défonce", "qui arrache" qui seraient possibles aussi. mais "qui tue" va peut-etre avec une certaine génération. A suivre. Existe-t-il des statistiques sur l'usage des mots/expressions? J'ai trouvé hier un site du CNRS contenant des corpus de textes, mais pas de statistiques.

Answer (score 1):

In French, we also say *meme*, the word *même* in French means "the same" in the internet meme context, because the memes are always the same, with the textual ones exception.

Looking in urban dictionnaries, *dank* means high quality, but with internet memes, dank is kind of ironical.

I would translate it by *Meme de grande qualité* or *Meme de haute qualité*. Emphasis on the irony used here, because dank memes are willingly ridiculous and/or bad.

*Note :* In my city we also say "dank meme", but although we speak French, we're in the southern part of Belgium.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the propositions, one may translate it to "Mèmes qui (en) jettent" or "Mèmes complètement j'tés".

It's another topic, but French medias try to impose /mème/ pronunciation, like "même word", whereas youth would more frequently if not always use the english pronuncition /mimze/ for memes.

Comment: Almost everyone I've met pronounce it *même* and not *meemee*.