# "Catchphrase" en français

Tags: traduction, anglais, usage, anglicismes

J'ai trouvé plusieurs mots en googlant pour traduire "catchphrase"

> slogan, rengaine, accroche, slogan accrocheur, phrase fétiche, phrase culte

Ces mots et expressions sont-ils interchangeables ? Peut-on employer le mot anglais tel quel ?

Comment: I've also heard "*phrase d'accroche*"

Comment: Une réponse retirée (et la question) parle aussi d'une _accroche_, on l'a sur [Larousse en ligne](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/accroche/549?q=accroche#547), et au [GDT](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8368900) depuis 15 ans en passant, et c'est bien aussi à mon avis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu as rencontré de nombreux mots traduisant *catchphrase* parce qu'une bonne traduction doit tenir compte du contexte.

S'il y avait un bijection entre chaque mot, verbe, adjectif, pronom, adverbe, etc. français et anglais, les outils de traduction automatique seraient depuis longtemps capables de produire des traductions sans défaut, ce qui est encore loin d'être le cas malgré les progrès accomplis.

Les mots que tu as trouvés ne sont donc pas (ou sont rarement) interchangeables mais peuvent être de bonnes traductions suivant le contexte où ils apparaissent.

Si l'on m'avait demandé la traduction la plus courante, j'aurais probablement d'abord choisi :

> ***[réplique culte](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9plique_culte)***.

Toutes les *catchphrases* ne sont pas des répliques de cinéma, de théâtre et autres spectacles, mais beaucoup les sont si l'on s'en tient aux listes disponibles sur Internet.

Culte a ici un sens élargi, décrit par l'Académie française comme suit :

> [C'est culte](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/cest-culte)
>   ...
>   Il s’emploie désormais en apposition pour montrer que telle personne, tel spectacle ou tel objet a des zélateurs qui lui vouent une admiration presque religieuse parce que, pense-t-on, il constitue une référence qu’on ne saurait ignorer. On parle ainsi d’auteur culte, de livre culte, de films culte. Si ce type de construction, qui relève le plus souvent de l’emphase, est accepté [...]

Il existe aussi une autre série de *catchphrases* qui ne proviennent pas du monde du spectacle mais de celui de la politique (*political catchphrases*), comme par exemple *ask not what your country can do for you...*, *one man, one vote* ou *read my lips, no more taxes*. En français, on parle alors souvent de **répliques** comme *vous n'avez pas le monopole du cœur*, *je vous demande de vous arrêter*, *la République, c'est moi* (cf. *l'état, c'est moi*) et aussi de **petites phrases**.

Voici un site qui regroupe un très grand nombre de *catchphrases* nommées *[**phrases et répliques cultes**](https://www.jokeme.fr/phrases-et-repliques-cultes.htm)*.

Le mot *catchphrase* est peu connu en français, je ne recommanderais pas de l'utiliser tel quel.

Comment: Il n'est ni de près ni de loin question de réplique dans le terme anglais « phrase » qui veut simplement dire « expression ».

Comment: @LPH ***You talkin' to me?*** Je sais parfaitement ce que veut dire *phrase* en anglais. Les *catchphrases* dont on parle le plus sont des ***répliques*** de films, de séries télévisées, d'animateurs de télévision et/ou humoristes. Voir https://dictionary.cambridge.org/fr/dictionnaire/anglais/catchphrase

Comment: Well, yes, who else? I checked the definition and it's about the same as what I get in other sources ; here is the beginning: **a phrase that is often repeated**; it's true that it is due to someone in particular, but nevertheless it does'nt go by the name of reply; this being said, there is nevertheless something exact in your answer, which I didn't realise and  mine is wrong in that respect; that's enough for my restituting a vote to your answer.

Comment: @LPH I think the vote is unlocked once the author edited his answer.

Comment: @dimitris Yes, thank you; I think that there is no other possibility.

Comment: @LPH By the way, why did you delete your answer? Am I missing something?

Comment: @dimitris It's only partly right; I confused advertising slogans with catch-phrases; too big a mistake to patch it up!

Comment: @LPH Thanks anyway for your exhaustive answers:-)!

Answer (score 2):

Non, aucun de ces termes mis à part « rengaine » (évidemment) n'est nécessairement une rengaine. Une rengaine est quelque chose de trop répété et donc qui lasse une audience.
Le seul terme qui s'approche de « catchphrase » est « phrase fétiche » et « phrase culte » ; ils sont tous les deux proposés dans la [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrase_f%C3%A9tiche).

On se base sur des définitions des dictionaires d'Oxford dans l'un desquels on lit

> « (dictionnaire d'Oxford 1) phrase in frequent current use »

alors que dans l'autre  on trouve

> « (dictionnaire d'Oxford 2, pour débutants) a phrase connected with the politician or entertainer who used it and made it famous ».

La définition du reverso confirme ces définitions et en fournit une extension non négligeable ;

> a well-known frequently used phrase, **esp. one associated with a particular group, etc**.

On voit donc que c'est une expression qui est issue de la bouche d'un politicien ou d'un personnage du monde du divertissement (entertainer) mais pas seulement ; n'importe quel groupe peut être l'origine. Mieux, l'origine peut être plus ou moins populaire.

La source suivante montre que l'on peut définir une catch phrase comme [suit](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-catchphrase-1689830) ;

> "'A catch phrase is a phrase that has caught on, and pleases the populace.' I'll go along with that, provided these substitutions be accepted: 'saying' for 'phrase'; and 'public' for the tendentious 'populace.'"
>   (Eric Partridge, A Dictionary of Catch Phrases. Routledge, 1986)

On ne doit pas, je crois associer ce concept avec celui de « witticism » , c'est à dire « trait d'esprit »; la « catch phrase » est rarement une phrase, presque toujours une expression, souvent  exclamative.

La fameuse Loi de Murphy (If nothing can go wrong something will.) n'est pas une « catch phrase ». N'en est pas une non plus
le mot d'esprit « Those that couldn't take it left it. », connu pour avoir été prononcé par le mathématicien et fondateur de la cybernétique, Norbert Wiener.

Cela est confirmé par la liste des « catch phrases » que propose [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_catchphrases).

On voit qu'il ne s'agit pas d'esprit ni de constructions linguistiques recherchées dans le sens de créér un impact. De plus on voit clairement dans cette liste qu'il ne s'agit pas de phrases mais d'expressions et parfois même pas autant, comme il peut ne s'agir que d'une interjection. Comme on doit s'en tenir à ce que sont les choses on ne peut pas parler de phrases.

Je crois qu'il faut absolument éviter le terme « culte », tout au moins dans le présent contexte : il n'est nullement question d'adoration et  ce terme n'est qu'ampoulé étant donné la solennité de laquelle il est empreint, laquelle n'a rien à voir dans ce contexte. « fétiche » n'est pas tellement mieux.

Une possibilité que j'entrevois est fondée sur le terme « leitmotiv » ;

> B.  P. anal. Idée, formule qui revient de façon constante (dans une œuvre littéraire, un discours de propagande ou de politique) avec une valeur symbolique et pour exprimer une préoccupation dominante. Synon. partiel refrain.

Je traduirais donc « catch phrase » par « **assimilation leitmotiv** ».

Le mot anglais « catchphrase » n'est pas dans le reverso ; donc personne ne l'utilise encore.

Comment: *Culte* n'est plus « empreint de sole**nn**ité » depuis longtemps. Un *leitmotiv* est déjà une formule, ce préfixe n'a guère de raison d'être. D'autre part, quand on parle de *leitmotiv*, c'est de quelque chose qui se répète au sein d'une œuvre unique, comme un refrain, alors qu'une *catchphrase*, c'est quelque chose qui est repris en dehors de son contexte original, dans d'autres œuvres, ou dans la vie courante, et qui peut aussi parfois évoluer, comme un [mème](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/13561/french-equivalent-of-the-english-internet-meme).

Comment: @jlliagre Je ne suis pas d'accord avec cette nouvelle utilisation du mot pour des choses comparativement grossières, loin de correspondre à son véritable esprit  dans les diverses religions ; il ne s'agit que d'engouement léger et frivole le plus souvent. La redondance qu'entraine le mot « formule » (c'est une spécialisation impossible, non formulée) est cependant inacceptable, je l'avoue. Cependant,  « valeur symbolique » et « exprimer une préoccupation dominante » rendent le terme apparemment idéal, à moins que je ne le saisisse pas trop bien.

Comment: Même l'Académie française, pourtant peu connue pour une attitude anticonformiste, rebelle, voire anarchiste, accepte cet usage de *culte*...

Comment: @jlliagre Je n'y peux rien, même les décisions de l'Académie, occasionnellement, ne me semblent pas des plus judicieuses.

Comment: Même quand elle écrit correctement *solennité* ?  ;-)

Comment: @jlliagre C'est l'anglais « solemn » qui m'embrouille encore, je l'ai probablement appris avant le français « solennel », merci.