# What is the gender of the word "mème" (Internet) in French?

Tags: articles, linguistique, langage-informel

I can't really find an answer anywhere, if it is ***le*** mème or ***la*** mème in French.
Would be glad if anyone knows something, it is for an art project about surrealism revival through social media.

Answer (score 5):

Unless there is a visible relationship with an already existing feminine French word, foreign words adopted in French are generally masculine and that's the case with ***un*** mème.

Beware that not everyone is already familiar with that word in French, especially as it collides with *même*.

See also [French equivalent of the English “internet meme”?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/13561/french-equivalent-of-the-english-internet-meme?r=SearchResults)

Answer (score 0):

I'm quoting Richard Dawkins, who created the term :

> Le vocable « même » semble lui-même constituer **un** bon mème.

(*Le Gène égoïste* [*The Selfish Gene*, OUP, 1976], Odile Jacob, 1996, chap. XII : « Les mèmes, nouveaux réplicateurs », note 2).

Comment: You are more precisely quoting Laura Ovion's translation.

Comment: True and important precision.